# Printing out multiple lines to console from if statements

Tags: java, netbeans

I need help printing multiple lines from if statements to the console. The code I have now is below however it will only print the average test score and what the student got but not the results on their first three test scores. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestScoresAndGrade {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Gathering info from user
        System.out.println("Enter your first test score!");
        int firstScore = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your second test score!");
        int secondScore = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Enter your third test score!");
        int thirdScore = keyboard.nextInt();
        
        int averageTestScore = (firstScore * secondScore * thirdScore)/3;
        
        // Telling the student what grade they got on the first test
        if (firstScore >= 90) {
            System.out.println("Congrats you got an A on your first test!");
        }
        else if (firstScore < 90 && firstScore > 80) {
            System.out.println("You got a B on your first test!");
        }
        else if (firstScore < 80 && firstScore > 70) {
            System.out.println("You got a C on your first test!");
        }
        else if (firstScore < 70 && firstScore > 60) {
            System.out.println("You got a D on your first test!");
        }
        else if (firstScore < 60) {
            System.out.println("You got a F on your first test!");
        }

        // Telling student what grade they got on the second test
        if (secondScore >= 90) {
            System.out.println("Congrats you got an A on your first test!");
        }
        else if (secondScore < 90 && secondScore > 80) {
            System.out.println("You got a B on your first test!");
        }
        else if (secondScore < 80 && secondScore > 70) {
            System.out.println("You got a C on your first test!");
        }
        else if (secondScore < 70 && secondScore > 60) {
            System.out.println("You got a D on your first test!");
        }
        else if (secondScore < 60) {
            System.out.println("You got a F on your first test!");
        }

        // Telling student what they got on third test
        if (thirdScore >= 90) {
            System.out.println("Congrats you got an A on your third test!");
        }
        else if (thirdScore < 90 && thirdScore > 80) {
            System.out.println("You got a B on your third test!");
        }
        else if (thirdScore < 80 && thirdScore > 70) {
            System.out.println("You got a C on your third test!");
        } 
        else if (thirdScore < 70 && thirdScore > 60) {
            System.out.println("You got a D on your third test!");
        }
        else if (thirdScore < 60) {
            System.out.println("You got a F on your third test!");
        }
        
        //Telling a student what there average score was    
        if (averageTestScore >= 90) {
            System.out.println("Congrats your avergage is an A!");
        }
        else if (averageTestScore < 90 && averageTestScore > 80) {
            System.out.println("Your average is a B!");
        }
        else if (averageTestScore < 80 && averageTestScore > 70) {
            System.out.println("Your average is a C!");
        }
        else if (averageTestScore < 70 && averageTestScore > 60) {
            System.out.println("Your average is a D!");
        }
        else if (averageTestScore < 60) {
            System.out.println("Your average is an F!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If your score is exactly 80 or exactly 70 or exactly 60 none of your conditions match it. Also your average is worked out wrong because you're multiplying the scores instead of adding them. Also when you write `else` you don't have to recheck the condition checked in the `if` statement. That's what `else` means.

Answer (score 0):

As @khelwood points out, you are excluding 80, 70, 60 from your if-else blocks. If you can provide a sample of your test data, we will have a better idea what it is happening.

On a side note,

1. We usually do if-else if-...else.(by convention last branch is else, unless you want to leave out some cases intentionally)
2. like @khelwood said, the average formula is wrong. One more thing, you should /3.0 if you want to get decimal since you are doing integer division here by 3.
3. If you want to improve the readability, think of encapsulating the duplicated logic and make it reusable.